# Autocomplete: how to have multiple values on data source

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, autocomplete

I'm not expert on js, so I'd like to use the code taken from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_autocomplete.asp) to implement Autocomplete input on my form.

Unfortunately, the example proposed show only one values on source data (see 'var countries').

I need to have multiple values on each Country. For example

```
    [{
    label: "Afghanistan",
    value: 100,
    id: 1, 
    },
    {
    label: "Albania",
    value: 101,
    id: 2, 
    },
    {
    label: "Algeria",
    value: 102,
    id: 3, 
    }]
```

And, if is possible, get all values (label, value, id) of selected country on php, when submit the form...

This is the example code of autocomplete:

```
function autocomplete(inp, arr) {
  /*the autocomplete function takes two arguments,
  the text field element and an array of possible autocompleted values:*/
  var currentFocus;
  /*execute a function when someone writes in the text field:*/
  inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
      var a, b, i, val = this.value;
      /*close any already open lists of autocompleted values*/
      closeAllLists();
      if (!val) { return false;}
      currentFocus = -1;
      /*create a DIV element that will contain the items (values):*/
      a = document.createElement("DIV");
      a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");
      /*append the DIV element as a child of the autocomplete container:*/
      this.parentNode.appendChild(a);
      /*for each item in the array...*/
      for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        /*check if the item starts with the same letters as the text field value:*/
        if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {
          /*create a DIV element for each matching element:*/
          b = document.createElement("DIV");
          /*make the matching letters bold:*/
          b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
          b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length);
          /*insert a input field that will hold the current array item's value:*/
          b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";
          /*execute a function when someone clicks on the item value (DIV element):*/
          b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
              /*insert the value for the autocomplete text field:*/
              inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
              /*close the list of autocompleted values,
              (or any other open lists of autocompleted values:*/
              closeAllLists();
          });
          a.appendChild(b);
        }
      }
  });
  /*execute a function presses a key on the keyboard:*/
  inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
      var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
      if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        /*If the arrow DOWN key is pressed,
        increase the currentFocus variable:*/
        currentFocus++;
        /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
        addActive(x);
      } else if (e.keyCode == 38) { //up
        /*If the arrow UP key is pressed,
        decrease the currentFocus variable:*/
        currentFocus--;
        /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
        addActive(x);
      } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        /*If the ENTER key is pressed, prevent the form from being submitted,*/
        e.preventDefault();
        if (currentFocus > -1) {
          /*and simulate a click on the "active" item:*/
          if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
        }
      }
  });
  function addActive(x) {
    /*a function to classify an item as "active":*/
    if (!x) return false;
    /*start by removing the "active" class on all items:*/
    removeActive(x);
    if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
    if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
    /*add class "autocomplete-active":*/
    x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
  }
  function removeActive(x) {
    /*a function to remove the "active" class from all autocomplete items:*/
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
    }
  }
  function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
    /*close all autocomplete lists in the document,
    except the one passed as an argument:*/
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
        x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  /*execute a function when someone clicks in the document:*/
  document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      closeAllLists(e.target);
  });
}

/*An array containing all the country names in the world:*/
var countries = ["Afghanistan","Albania","Algeria","Andorra","Angola","Anguilla","Antigua & Barbuda","Argentina","Armenia","Aruba","Australia","Austria","Azerbaijan","Bahamas","Bahrain","Bangladesh","Barbados","Belarus","Belgium","Belize","Benin","Bermuda","Bhutan","Bolivia","Bosnia & Herzegovina","Botswana","Brazil","British Virgin Islands","Brunei","Bulgaria","Burkina Faso","Burundi","Cambodia","Cameroon","Canada","Cape Verde","Cayman Islands","Central Arfrican Republic","Chad","Chile","China","Colombia","Congo","Cook Islands","Costa Rica","Cote D Ivoire","Croatia","Cuba","Curacao","Cyprus","Czech Republic","Denmark","Djibouti","Dominica","Dominican Republic","Ecuador","Egypt","El Salvador","Equatorial Guinea","Eritrea","Estonia","Ethiopia","Falkland Islands","Faroe Islands","Fiji","Finland","France","French Polynesia","French West Indies","Gabon","Gambia","Georgia","Germany","Ghana","Gibraltar","Greece","Greenland","Grenada","Guam","Guatemala","Guernsey","Guinea","Guinea Bissau","Guyana","Haiti","Honduras","Hong Kong","Hungary","Iceland","India","Indonesia","Iran","Iraq","Ireland","Isle of Man","Israel","Italy","Jamaica","Japan","Jersey","Jordan","Kazakhstan","Kenya","Kiribati","Kosovo","Kuwait","Kyrgyzstan","Laos","Latvia","Lebanon","Lesotho","Liberia","Libya","Liechtenstein","Lithuania","Luxembourg","Macau","Macedonia","Madagascar","Malawi","Malaysia","Maldives","Mali","Malta","Marshall Islands","Mauritania","Mauritius","Mexico","Micronesia","Moldova","Monaco","Mongolia","Montenegro","Montserrat","Morocco","Mozambique","Myanmar","Namibia","Nauro","Nepal","Netherlands","Netherlands Antilles","New Caledonia","New Zealand","Nicaragua","Niger","Nigeria","North Korea","Norway","Oman","Pakistan","Palau","Palestine","Panama","Papua New Guinea","Paraguay","Peru","Philippines","Poland","Portugal","Puerto Rico","Qatar","Reunion","Romania","Russia","Rwanda","Saint Pierre & Miquelon","Samoa","San Marino","Sao Tome and Principe","Saudi Arabia","Senegal","Serbia","Seychelles","Sierra Leone","Singapore","Slovakia","Slovenia","Solomon Islands","Somalia","South Africa","South Korea","South Sudan","Spain","Sri Lanka","St Kitts & Nevis","St Lucia","St Vincent","Sudan","Suriname","Swaziland","Sweden","Switzerland","Syria","Taiwan","Tajikistan","Tanzania","Thailand","Timor L'Este","Togo","Tonga","Trinidad & Tobago","Tunisia","Turkey","Turkmenistan","Turks & Caicos","Tuvalu","Uganda","Ukraine","United Arab Emirates","United Kingdom","United States of America","Uruguay","Uzbekistan","Vanuatu","Vatican City","Venezuela","Vietnam","Virgin Islands (US)","Yemen","Zambia","Zimbabwe"];

/*initiate the autocomplete function on the "myInput" element, and pass along the countries array as possible autocomplete values:*/
autocomplete(document.getElementById("myInput"), countries);
```

```
<form autocomplete="off" action="/action_page.php">
  <div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;">
    <input id="myInput" type="text" name="myCountry" placeholder="Country">
  </div>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

EDIT: In add, instead of form with action="/action_page.php, I have the following code that filter result with ajax:

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url() ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" method="POST" id="filter">      
  <input type="checkbox" name="myfield1" value="myfield1">
  <label for="myfield1"><span id="text_myfield1">Myfield1</span></label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="myfield2" value="myfield2">
  <label for="myfield2"><span id="text_myfield2">Myfield2</span></label>

  <button id="button-filtra">Filtra</button>    
  <input type="hidden" value="inputfilter" class="submit" id="button-filter" name="action">

</form>
```

```
if(isset($_POST['myfield1'])) {
    $myfield1 = $_POST['myfield1'];
}
if(isset($_POST['myfield2'])) {
    $myfield2 = $_POST['myfield2'];
}
```

```
jQuery(function($){     

$(document).on("submit", "form#filter", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // Check for validations.
  // 
    
        var filter = $('#filter');
        $.ajax({
            url:filter.attr('action'),
            data:filter.serialize(), // form data
            type:filter.attr('method'), // POST
            beforeSend:function(xhr){
                filter.find('button').text('Filtrando...'); // changing the button label
                
            },
            success:function(data){
                filter.find('button').text('Filtra'); // changing the button label back
                $('#response').html(data); // insert data
                
            }
         
        });
        return false;   
    
  // Rest of the code here.
});
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible with your code, you just have to access the object elements for each country as show in the `for` loop below which is also part of the entire code. You need to access the country parameters as `arr[i].label`, `arr[i].id`, `arr[i].value`.

```js
/*for each item in the array...*/
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    /*check if the item starts with the same letters as the text field value:*/
    if (arr[i].label.substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {
        /*create a DIV element for each matching element:*/
        b = document.createElement("DIV");
        /*make the matching letters bold:*/
        b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].label.substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
        b.innerHTML += arr[i].label.substr(val.length);
        /*insert a input field that will hold the current array item's value:*/
        b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' id='" + arr[i].id + "' value='" + arr[i].value + "' data-label='" + arr[i].label + "'>";
        /*execute a function when someone clicks on the item value (DIV element):*/
        b.addEventListener("click", function (e) {

            /* Selected option */
            const selectedCountry = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];

            /* Selected country data */
            const selectedCountryLabel = selectedCountry.getAttribute('data-label');
            const selectedCountryValue = selectedCountry.value;
            const selectedCountryId = selectedCountry.getAttribute('id');

            /*insert the value for the autocomplete text field:*/
            inp.value = selectedCountryLabel;

            /*close the list of autocompleted values,
            (or any other open lists of autocompleted values:*/
            closeAllLists();

            /* Remove country fields to avoid piling of previous fields */
            const countryFields = document.getElementsByClassName('country-field');

            while (countryFields.length > 0) countryFields[0].remove();

            /* Create a hidden input field for country label */
            let countryLabel = document.createElement('input');
            countryLabel.setAttribute('class', 'country-field country-label');
            countryLabel.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
            countryLabel.setAttribute('name', 'country-label');
            countryLabel.setAttribute('value', `${selectedCountryLabel}`);

            /* Create a hidden input field for country value */
            let countryValue = document.createElement('input');
            countryValue.setAttribute('class', 'country-field country-value');
            countryValue.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
            countryValue.setAttribute('name', 'country-value');
            countryValue.setAttribute('value', `${selectedCountryValue}`);

            /* Create a hidden input field for country id */
            let countryId = document.createElement('input');
            countryId.setAttribute('class', 'country-field country-id');
            countryId.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
            countryId.setAttribute('name', 'country-id');
            countryId.setAttribute('value', `${selectedCountryId}`);

            /* Append the hidden fields to the current (#myInput) field  */
            inp.parentNode.insertBefore(countryLabel, inp.nextSibling);
            inp.parentNode.insertBefore(countryValue, inp.nextSibling);
            inp.parentNode.insertBefore(countryId, inp.nextSibling);
        });
        a.appendChild(b);
    }
}
```

I have also added Bulgaria to the country array for thorough testing.

```js
/*An array containing all the country names in the world:*/
var countries = [{
        label: "Afghanistan",
        value: 100,
        id: 1,
    },
    {
        label: "Albania",
        value: 101,
        id: 2,
    },
    {
        label: "Algeria",
        value: 102,
        id: 3,
    },
    {
        label: "Bulgaria",
        value: 103,
        id: 4,
    }
];
```

Here is the entire code snippet. Run it below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font: 16px Arial;  
}

/*the container must be positioned relative:*/
.autocomplete {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

input {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

input[type=text] {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
}

input[type=submit] {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.autocomplete-items {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top: none;
  z-index: 99;
  /*position the autocomplete items to be the same width as the container:*/
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.autocomplete-items div {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fff; 
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d4d4d4; 
}

/*when hovering an item:*/
.autocomplete-items div:hover {
  background-color: #e9e9e9; 
}

/*when navigating through the items using the arrow keys:*/
.autocomplete-active {
  background-color: DodgerBlue !important; 
  color: #ffffff; 
}
</style>
</head>     
<body>

<h2>Autocomplete</h2>

<p>Start typing:</p>

<!--Make sure the form has the autocomplete function switched off:-->
<form autocomplete="off" action="/action_page.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;">
    <input id="myInput" type="text" name="myCountry" placeholder="Country">
  </div>
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<script>
function autocomplete(inp, arr) {
  /*the autocomplete function takes two arguments,
  the text field element and an array of possible autocompleted values:*/
  var currentFocus;
  /*execute a function when someone writes in the text field:*/
  inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
      var a, b, i, val = this.value;
      /*close any already open lists of autocompleted values*/
      closeAllLists();
      if (!val) { return false;}
      currentFocus = -1;
      /*create a DIV element that will contain the items (values):*/
      a = document.createElement("DIV");
      a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");
      /*append the DIV element as a child of the autocomplete container:*/
      this.parentNode.appendChild(a);
      /*for each item in the array...*/
      for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        /*check if the item starts with the same letters as the text field value:*/
        if (arr[i].label.substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {
          /*create a DIV element for each matching element:*/
          b = document.createElement("DIV");
          /*make the matching letters bold:*/
          b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].label.substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
          b.innerHTML += arr[i].label.substr(val.length);
          /*insert a input field that will hold the current array item's value:*/
          b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' id='" + arr[i].id + "' value='" + arr[i].value + "' data-label='" + arr[i].label + "'>";
          /*execute a function when someone clicks on the item value (DIV element):*/
          b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
              
              /* Selected option */
              const selectedCountry = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];

              /* Selected country data */
              const selectedCountryLabel = selectedCountry.getAttribute('data-label');
              const selectedCountryValue = selectedCountry.value;
              const selectedCountryId    = selectedCountry.getAttribute('id');

              /*insert the value for the autocomplete text field:*/
              inp.value = selectedCountryLabel;

              /*close the list of autocompleted values,
              (or any other open lists of autocompleted values:*/
              closeAllLists();
              
              /* Remove country fields to avoid piling of previous fields */
              const countryFields = document.getElementsByClassName('country-field');

              while (countryFields.length > 0) countryFields[0].remove();
              
              /* Create a hidden input field for country label */
              let countryLabel = document.createElement('input');
              countryLabel.setAttribute('class', 'country-field country-label');
              countryLabel.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
              countryLabel.setAttribute('name', 'country-label');
              countryLabel.setAttribute('value', `${selectedCountryLabel}`);
              
              /* Create a hidden input field for country value */
              let countryValue = document.createElement('input');
              countryValue.setAttribute('class', 'country-field country-value');
              countryValue.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
              countryValue.setAttribute('name', 'country-value');
              countryValue.setAttribute('value', `${selectedCountryValue}`);
              
              /* Create a hidden input field for country id */
              let countryId = document.createElement('input');
              countryId.setAttribute('class', 'country-field country-id');
              countryId.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
              countryId.setAttribute('name', 'country-id');
              countryId.setAttribute('value', `${selectedCountryId}`);

              /* Append the hidden fields to the current (#myInput) field  */
              inp.parentNode.insertBefore(countryLabel, inp.nextSibling);
              inp.parentNode.insertBefore(countryValue, inp.nextSibling);
              inp.parentNode.insertBefore(countryId, inp.nextSibling);
          });
          a.appendChild(b);
        }
      }
  });
  /*execute a function presses a key on the keyboard:*/
  inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
      var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
      if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        /*If the arrow DOWN key is pressed,
        increase the currentFocus variable:*/
        currentFocus++;
        /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
        addActive(x);
      } else if (e.keyCode == 38) { //up
        /*If the arrow UP key is pressed,
        decrease the currentFocus variable:*/
        currentFocus--;
        /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
        addActive(x);
      } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        /*If the ENTER key is pressed, prevent the form from being submitted,*/
        e.preventDefault();
        if (currentFocus > -1) {
          /*and simulate a click on the "active" item:*/
          if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
        }
      }
  });
  function addActive(x) {
    /*a function to classify an item as "active":*/
    if (!x) return false;
    /*start by removing the "active" class on all items:*/
    removeActive(x);
    if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
    if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
    /*add class "autocomplete-active":*/
    x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
  }
  function removeActive(x) {
    /*a function to remove the "active" class from all autocomplete items:*/
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
    }
  }
  function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
    /*close all autocomplete lists in the document,
    except the one passed as an argument:*/
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
        x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  /*execute a function when someone clicks in the document:*/
  document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      closeAllLists(e.target);
  });
}


/*An array containing all the country names in the world:*/
var countries = [{
    label: "Afghanistan",
    value: 100,
    id: 1, 
    },
    {
    label: "Albania",
    value: 101,
    id: 2, 
    },
    {
    label: "Algeria",
    value: 102,
    id: 3, 
    },
    {
    label: "Bulgaria",
    value: 103,
    id: 4, 
    }];

/*initiate the autocomplete function on the "myInput" element, and pass along the countries array as possible autocomplete values:*/
autocomplete(document.getElementById("myInput"), countries);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT 1:**

I have added new JavaScript code to have a hidden input field that send the selected country values as an object which is processed using PHP.

I have also updated the form to have `method="post"`.

Sample PHP code for the `action_page.php`.

```php
$countryInput = json_decode($_POST['country-input'], true);

$label = $countryInput['label'];
$value = $countryInput['value'];
$id = $countryInput['id'];

print_r($label);
echo '<br />';
print_r($value);
echo '<br />';
print_r($id);
```

**EDIT 2:**

I hope you had mentioned WordPress earlier. Anyway I have created solution that implements WordPress AJAX process. I have not tested it but it should work.

**Step 1:**
Create a script file called ***my-country-script.js*** and add the code below.

```js
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : ajaxurl,
    dataType : 'json',
    cache : false,
    data : {
        action : 'so73513971_process_country_data',
        country_input : $('input[name="country-input"]').val()
    },
    success : function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

**Step 2:**
Add the code provided below in your functions.php file or main plugin file if your are using a plugin. The purpose of this code is to enqueue the script we added.

```php
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'so73513971_enqueue_country_js');
function so73513971_enqueue_country_js()
{
    wp_enqueue_script('my_country_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/my-country-script.js');
    wp_localize_script(
        'my_country_script',
        'ajax_vars',
        array(
            'url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')
        )
    );
}
```

**Step 3:**
Add the code below in your functions.php file to process the AJAX post request.

```php
add_action( 'wp_ajax_so73513971_process_country_data', 'so73513971_process_country_data' );
function so73513971_process_country_data()
{
    $response = [];
    
    $countryInput = isset($_POST['country_input']) ? json_decode($_POST['country_input'], true) : null;
    
    if ($countryInput !== null) {
        
        $label = $countryInput['label'];
        $value = $countryInput['value'];
        $id = $countryInput['id'];
        
        $response['success'] = 1;
        $response['message'] = __('Saved successfully.', 'so73513971');
        $response['data']    = array(
            'label' => $label,
            'value' => $value,
            'id' => $id
        );
        
    } else {
        $response['success'] = 0;
        $response['message'] = __('Error! Saving failed.', 'so73513971');
    }
    
    echo json_encode($response);

    die; // Don't delete this
}
```

**EDIT 3:**

Add the different country form fields separately instead of object so that they be serialized with other form inputs.

Comment: Hello @Rodgath, thanks a lot for your useful response. I have a couple of doubts: 1- when user inser country and select it, is it possible to show the label? With your code is inserted the value. 2- how I can pass in php these three values (label, value, id) of selected country?

Comment: @James check the updated answer. I have made improvements as you have requested.

Comment: your code is great and works, thanks a lot for that @Rodgath. Only that my form works with ajax, I have <form action="<?php echo site_url() ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" method="POST" id="filter"> and I have a function jQuery to filter the result with ajax. With all other submit values I use 'isset'... Now I tried to add your suggest php code but seems that it doesn't work with my form... Do you have any suggest? Sorry but I'm not expert on js with php

Comment: I update the first post to show how is my form and function to filter result with ajax @Rodgath.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Also, you do not need `action="<?php echo site_url() ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php"` in your form because we are using JavaScript to process the form. Just use `action=""` and it will be ok.

Comment: Sorry for not told you that I use WordPress before. I very appreciated all your code, thank you very much!!! Anyway I added all your code but I'm not able to retrieve the values on php with sample PHP code that you have suggested for action_page.php. Take in account that I have other values that I taken on php from input by isset post, but these additional value from json I'm not able to retrieve... I update again first post to show better what I have now in my form and how get value in php and use filter by ajax

Comment: You don't have to use the action_page.php because we are now using ajax. For the other values, just extend the AJAX JavaScript file to fetch all the form submission values.

Comment: Obviousely I'm not using action_page.php. I added that code on my template and I don't get any value from echo $label $value and $id. Did you take in account that I already have ajax function to filter post when form is submitted (see my first post)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247621/discussion-between-rodgath-and-james).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions that you made to me in chat @Rodgath. Very good person.

Answer (score 1):

try it!

```html
<input list="browsers" name="browser">
<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
</datalist>
```

Comment: Please explain how you approached the question and arrived at the solution.

Comment: @Zheng Zhang your reply is OT

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).